# Multiline Textbox Columns C#

Tags: c#, textbox, multiline

So as apart of my course work I have to output the totals sales of 5 books by their author. Here is an example as to how it should look:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9wQD.png)

My question is how can I achieve an output in the text box where the Author names are in a fixed position like above. I would suspect you could do this with columns but I'm still learning and yet to have any experience with them. After this I need to sort the lists based on price relative to the authors. Currently I just have a simple output that pushes out the numbers from an array storing the total sales:

```
private void uiAuthorChartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateAuthorSales();

        uiAuthorChartTextBox.Clear();

        for (int outputAuthorChart = 0; outputAuthorChart <= salesByAuthor.Length - 1; outputAuthorChart++)
        uiAuthorChartTextBox.AppendText("£" + salesByAuthor[outputAuthorChart].ToString() + "\r\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [PadRight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34d75d7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Allows you to pad out a string with spaces. If you do a bit of maths with the size of string required, and the length of the string you have, you should be able to calculate the number of spaces needed.

I will leave you to implement it, because the best way to learn is by doing.

Comment: Thought \t worked i will still check it out, Thanks :)

Comment: Tab (\t) will work for simple applications, however if the price was high enough, a tab wouldn't align everything up. Just something to think about when you are dealing with unknown data. A more robust solution would be to probably check all the data to be displayed, and find what the optimal padding (or tabbing) that is required to display it nicely.

Comment: I got it working using both, the stock is set to so for one seller the maximum is about 2000.00. With PadRight it was meaning the others where not aligned when at lower values by by adding \t back in it still Pads further to the right and stays in-line with the others:        uiAuthorChartTextBox.AppendText("£" + salesByAuthor[outputAuthorChart].ToString().PadRight(15) + "\t" + bookAuthors[outputAuthorChart] + "\r\n");

Answer (score 1):

You can use one or more tab characters `\t` before the author name in the string

Comment: Thank you very much can't believe it was that simple!